# TYPO3 tx_news: Detail category link with sorting List

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, tx-news, typo3-11.x

So far the linking etc. in the news detail for the category output works fine.
What does not work yet is the "filtering" when i click (the site: News Detail) on a category "link" => Here it should then filter the news matching the category on the news list.

What i need on Settings on the News Detail-Site?
What i need in the Template from the News Detail?

Here the News Detail category FLUID:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.categories}">
                |
                <span class="news-list-category">
                    <f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category" iteration="iteratorCategories">
                        <f:spaceless>
                        <f:if condition="{category.shortcut}">
                            <f:then>
                                <f:link.action pageUid="{category.shortcut}" arguments="{overwriteDemand:{categories:category.uid}}" class="news-list-category__item" title="{category.title}">{category.title}</f:link.action>
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else><f:link.action pageUid="{settings.backPid}" arguments="{overwriteDemand:{categories:category.uid}}" class="news-list-category__item" title="{category.title}">{category.title}</f:link.action></f:else>
                        </f:if>
                        </f:spaceless><f:spaceless><f:if condition="{iteratorCategories.isLast}"><f:then></f:then><f:else>,</f:else></f:if></f:spaceless>
                    </f:for>
                </span>
            </f:if>
```

the focus is this fluid:

```
<f:link.action pageUid="{settings.backPid}" arguments="{overwriteDemand:{categories:category.uid}}">{category.title}</f:link.action>
```

if i click on the link, the news list is default, and not sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `overwriteDemand` is not allowed on your list-page.

There's a section "[Set overwriteDemand in links](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Tutorials/Templates/OverwriteDemandInFrontend/Index.html)" in the documentation saying:

> Important
>
> The checkbox **Disable override demand** in the list plugin (Tab
> Additional) must **not** be set to allow overriding the properties.

Comment: Thanks!!! A small checkbox in the News-Plugin was the triggern :D